# Set the width and height of ANY window to a particular value(s) without manually resizing

Tags: windows-7, window

In Windows 7, I want to be able to set the size of any application's window to an exact value(s).

For example, I have Paint, Notepad, VLC Player and Explorer open. I want to set Paint's window to 1000x800, Notepad to 800x600, VLC Player's window to 1200x800 and Explorer's window to 600x400 etc..

Is there a program that I can use to set window sizes (for ANY open windows) as exact values?

Something like.. Right click on title bar of ANY window and choose "Resize to.." and then giving some width and height in a dialog box, and the window is resized to that value. Some app makes it possible?

P.S. Answer to the first comment that is going to be posted - "Why would you want to do that?"... I am too tired to answer that question. If you absolutely must know, please assume it is because I am bored.

Comment: No it is not. I am not talking about windows remembering the size. I am talking about setting it... through other means than manually resizing.

Comment: I do not know if it was a coincidence, but right after installing SIZER my Windows interface totally malfunctioned - the start menu got transparent windows was not refreshing and I could not click anything. I had to disable transparency in Windows 10 to fix this. Did anyone have such an issue too? I ended up using this : https://www.mindgems.com/article/resize-window-to-specific-size-set-window-size-in-pixels/
Actually I am quite happy with it as it is really easy. If you press CTRL+SHIF+R on any window a dialog appears and you can enter the sizes that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using a free utility called [Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer) for some time on Windows XP. I just checked the website and it's now Vista and Win7 compatible.

It won't resize a bunch of Windows for you all at once, but you can predefine a bunch of size & location combinations and give them each labels, which can then be assigned to a window.  It has an online [user guide](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/userguide.html) for more detailed information.

As I mentioned, I've been using it a long time and have found it to be very useful.